# MVC3 Map Route Using String Identifier in Action Segment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to route using a very simple human-readable url, like so:

I want to route like so:  `/Controller/Title-Of-The-EF-Object`

I don't want `/Controller/Action/ABCDEF01-2345-6789-0ABC-DEF01234` 
or
`/Controller/Action/Title-Of-The-EF-Object`.  Action is handled by the route, so the url should only include the controller and identifier string.

My entities contain a unique, sanitized UrlTitle string as a property:

```
public class Entity {
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    //Example: "Title of the EF object"
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //Example: "Title-Of-The-EF-Object"
    public string UrlTitle { set; set; }
}
```

Current route mapping:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Item",
            "{controller}/{UrlTitle}",
            new { controller = "{controller}", action = "Details" }
        );
```

The problem is that when requesting `/Controller/Title-Of-The-EF-Object`, MVC is interpreting `Title-Of-The-EF-Object` as an action because a) it's a string, and b) where it falls in the segment, so I keep getting Resource Cannot Be Found.  I can get it working if I use the entity's Guid instead of the UrlTitle, because MVC interprets the Guid as such.

How do I create a custom route map for `{controller}/{id_string}`?

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me as I was typing the question.  Routes were in the wrong order.  *0_0*

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Item",
        "{controller}/{UrlTitle}",
        new { controller = "{controller}", action = "Details" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```